# Why is my Button unclickable when I click on one of its child controls and why can't I change the cursor to arrow on the inner Labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been trying to make a chat application so I have added a new table adapter that returns the current user groupchats with their respective names and profiles and the date of the last message sent, and then dynamically created the group chats when the user loads the application.Disclaimer: I used gunaUI2 library, so here's the code I came up with:

```
Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button btnChat = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2Button();
btnChat.Size = new Size(chatsPanel.Width - 5, chatsPanel.Height / 10);
btnChat.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
btnChat.BorderColor = Color.Black;
btnChat.BorderThickness = 1;
btnChat.BorderRadius = 5;
btnChat.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(40,40,40);
chatsPanel.Controls.Add(btnChat);
Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2CirclePictureBox profilePic = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2CirclePictureBox();
profilePic.Size = new Size(btnChat.Height - 4, btnChat.Height - 4);
profilePic.Location = new Point(3, 3);
if (x["ProfilePicture"] != null && x["ProfilePicture"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    byte[] imageData = (byte[])x["ProfilePicture"];
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
    {
        using (Image profileImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
        {
            profilePic.Image = new Bitmap(profileImage);
        }
    }
}
else profilePic.Image = Resources._58512eb4e598b5ea4e2414e3c115bef9;
profilePic.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
profilePic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
profilePic.Click +=  new EventHandler(ProfilePic_Click);
btnChat.Controls.Add(profilePic);
Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel lblUser = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel();
lblUser.Text = x["username"].ToString();
lblUser.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);
lblUser.Location=new Point(profilePic.Width+5, profilePic.Height/2-lblUser.Height/2);
lblUser.ForeColor = Color.Beige;
lblUser.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
btnChat.Controls.Add(lblUser);
Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel lblTime = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel();
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(x["TimeStamp"].ToString());
if(date.Date==DateTime.Now.Date)
    lblTime.Text = date.ToString("hh:mm tt");
else lblTime.Text = date.ToString("g");
lblTime.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7);
lblTime.Location = new Point(btnChat.Width-lblTime.Width-2, profilePic.Height*3 / 4 );
lblTime.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
lblTime.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
btnChat.Controls.Add(lblTime);
Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel lblConversationID = new Guna.UI2.WinForms.Guna2HtmlLabel();
lblConversationID.Text = x["ConversationID"].ToString();
lblConversationID.Visible = false;
btnChat.Controls.Add(lblConversationID);
btnChat.Click += new EventHandler(btnGroup_Click);
lblUser.Click += new EventHandler(btnGroupLabel_Click);
lblTime.Click += new EventHandler(btnGroupLabel_Click);`
```

the problem here is that the button can't be pressed when I press over the label so I added the last two lines to a new event and the other problems is that the cursor is of type I-Cursor as if it's above text even though I tried the to manually change the cursor to arrow, and the other problem is that the buttons would change back-color when hovered above but that isn't the case if it's hovering above any of the controls inside it

Comment: You should build an UserControl instead of trying to add Controls to a standard Control

Comment: It indicates that the program is hung, no longer responding to messages from the OS.  Use Debug > Break All and Debug > Windows > Call Stack to see what it is doing.  Second time I've seen a question about "Guna" btw, they got some *weird* problems.